# What is the right way to count rows?

Tags: r, dplyr, count, row, weighted-average

I have a dataset and in the description is written <<In order to improve the representativeness of some segments of the population, the variable `pesofit` (sample weight) has been inserted. The use of sample weights is recommended to obtain unbiased estimates. >>

Here a sample

```
> head(data_shape, 10)
# A tibble: 10 × 5
   tpens  ireg pens_PPP apqual pesofit
   <dbl> <int>    <dbl>  <int>   <dbl>
 1  1800    18    21.1      15   0.380
 2   900     5     8.91     16   1.45 
 3   500    13     5.40     16   0.869
 4  1211    13    13.1      15   0.238
 5  2100    13    22.7      15   0.238
 6   700     8     6.43     15   0.882
 7  2000     9    17.9      15   1.25 
 8  1200     5    11.9      15   1.67 
 9  2000     4    17.8      15   3.37 
10   880    15     9.62     15   1.69
```

1. `tpens` = is the wage
2. `ireg` = is the code of the geographical area where the individual lives
3. `pesofit` = is the sample weight

I'm using this `pesofit` to compute the weighted means and also for the weighted linear regresion.

I need also to count the number of wages in each geographical area ( `ireg`). Should I use `pesofit` also to count? Or is it enough just counting the number of rows for each value of `ireg`?

In that case, how can I do?

Comment: This seems to be more a statistical than a programming question. You may be better off moving this to the Cross Validated site for statistics questions: https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: I already tried in Cross Validated, but that forum seems dead. @G.Grothendieck , I'm sorry to bother you, but you helped me with the question about the coefficient of the linear regression... have you any idea about this instead?